# How can I create a shortcut on the left side in Caja (CentOS7)

Tags: centos, caja

I run [Caja](https://www.google.com/search?q=Caja+File+Manager&oq=Caja+File+Manager&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l6j69i60.2323j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on CentOS7 and wondered if I could add a shortcut down the left side to a folder (acting as a (network)drive) or replace the 'Desktop', 'Documents' etc. shortcuts down the left side with my own shortcuts and/or rename them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they’re defined in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks. You’d use file:///path/to/directory syntax.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a go.

Comment: Thank you so much, answer worked and accepted. - Note, please could you have a look at my drive mounting question because I'm stuck with it not recognising `_netfs` in the fstab line...

Comment: Can you help with this? @jsbillings [LINK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591250/change-write-permissions-on-samba-share-mount-centos7)

Comment: Just revisited this and realised it only works for root, if I try on a standard user, I get it saying it's creating a new file when I run `vim ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`